# Using flocks with mutiple instances of a program

Tags: c

I am programming a counter in c that makes use of flocks to run multiple instances of the counter program. The program reads and writes from a file, incrementing the value in the file. When I run the multiple instances, the file contains the correct values but when I run the file once (./count5) , the values in the file stops at 3000 but it is suppose to stop at 500 because the while loop ends at 500. Any help would be appreciated.

```
while(cnt < 500)
{   
    struct flock lock = {F_WRLCK, SEEK_SET, 0, 0, 0};

    lock.l_pid = getpid();
    fd = open("num3",  O_RDWR | O_APPEND);

    if (fcntl (fd, F_SETLKW, &lock) != -1) /* Set the lock to wait while another instance is already running */
    {
        fp1 = fopen("num3", "a+");  /*Read from file*/

        while(fgets(buff, 255, fp1) != NULL);   /*Moves to last line of file*/


        i = atoi(buff); /*Convert buff to int*/
        i++;    /*Increment the value*/

        sprintf(temp,"%d\n", i); /*Prints the incremented value to temp*/
        fputs(temp, fp1);
        fclose(fp1);

        lock.l_type = F_UNLCK;
        fcntl(fd, F_SETLK, &lock);
        close(fd);

        cnt++;  /*Increment counter*/

    }


}
```

Comment: You seem to be writing the value `i` to the file. So the values that get written depend on what is already in the file.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be writing the value `i` to the file. So the values that get written depend on what is already in the file. –  Greg Hewgill